# How to format a string returned by a PHP function

Tags: php

I wrote a program that uses an ISBN to query Amazon for that ISBN's price, and returns the following result:

```
5cb66919-8a8d-4c13-9175-790f0476508d0.0401580000000000TrueISBN9780340979266OffersAllAll0340979267809USD$8.09688USD$6.88598USD$5.98241010000
```

I need to format this so that I have the price information in a format that would be understandable to a human.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you scraping this text from html? You should try using [Amazon's API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html).

Comment: Not trying to be mean but there is an Amazon API for this.  I applaud you for your efforts.  Check out this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html it contains everything you would want to query items and retrieve information about them.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The response looks like coming from amazon's api- does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this way..

```
<?php
$s = '5cb66919-8a8d-4c13-9175-790f0476508d0.0401580000000000TrueISBN9780340979266OffersAllAll0340979267809USD$8.09688USD$6.88598USD$5.982410100000';
$p = explode('USD',$s);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($p);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnPrice($response){
    $prices = explode('USD',$response);
    unset($prices[0]);
    return $prices;
}
```